# How to launch a process on Linux with highly restricted privileges?

Tags: linux, security, process

I'd like to (from code) launch a process with highly restricted privileges.

- Can save files, but only in its own folder and limited to a quota.
- Can use memory, within a quota.
- CPU time (including any subprocesses it launches) is limited to a quota.
- Can't talk with any other process except it's own and the interface to my controller program via stdin/out.
- Can't interact with any devices.
- Can't see anything else on the network.

(I'm building a grid-esque system. The launched code may be hostile.)

Here's what I've got so far...
 - In advance, create some users, grid00-grid99. Give each one disk/memory/CPU quota as configured.

To launch a process...

- Pick an unused gridxx user.
- Make a folder inside the user's home folder.
- Hard link /bin, /usr, etc in that folder.
- Make a new /home/gridxx and /tmp folders in that folder.
- Copy in the program files.
- Switch to the gridxx user.
- chroot to the new folder.
- Launch the new process.

Have I missed anything?

Many thanks.

Comment: You'd probably get more answers on serverfault.com

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd be doing all this from code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard resource usage limits (via `ulimit`) can handle the first three, and SELinux can handle the other three. Simply create a new domain for the application, assign the proper permissions, and away you go (but not it).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for something like the [FreeBSD jail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) feature. (That's for FreeBSD of course, but that page has links to similar technologies for Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish that with ulimit, chroot, disk quotas, and a firewall. Limiting all forms of "talking" (IPC) is hard. In the end you may want to go with a set of virtual machines.